# PHP email contact form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, email

I've created a PHP email contact form and it works. Now in addition I have used Javascript to add extra dropdown lists to the form where the user can select the option. I'd like those  chosen options from the new drop down lists to be added to the PHP email contact form message content.

Just wondering if anyone can help.

EMAIL FORM

```
<form method='post' action='sendeailme.php'>
<form>
    <table width="766" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="258"><span class="asdwd">
            <label>Name</label>
          </span>
            </td>
            <td width="255"><span class="asdwd">
            <label>Number</label>
          </span>
            </td>
            <td width="239"><span class="asdwd">
            <label>Email</label>
          </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p class="asdwd">
        <input name="name" placeholder="Your Name" id="name">
        <input name="number" placeholder="Your Number" id="number">
        <input name="email" placeholder="Your Name" id="email">
    </p>
    <table width="766" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="261"><span class="asdwd">
     <label>Occasion</label>
   </span>
            </td>
            <td width="255"><span class="asdwd">
     <label>Venues</label>
   </span>
            </td>
            <td width="239"><span class="asdwd">
     <label>Date of the Event </label>
   </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input name="Occasion" placeholder="Your Email" id="Occasion">
        <input name="Venues" placeholder="Your Email" id="Venues">
        <input name="date" placeholder="Your Email" id="date">
    </p>
    <table width="812" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="366"><span class="asdwd">
           <label>Menu Options</label>
           </span>
            </td>
            <td width="237"><span class="asdwd">
           <label>Number of Guests</label>
         </span>
            </td>
            <td width="195"><span class="asdwd">
           <label>Human Verification</label>
         </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><div id="mainContainer">
              <div>
                <select name="custom" id="custom">
                  <option value="t1">t1</option>
                  <option value="t2">t2</option>
                  <option value="t3">t3</option>
                </select>
                <input type="button" id="add_new" value=" + " onClick="addNew();">
              </div>
            </div>                  <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
            <td height="47">
                <input name="guests" id="guests" placeholder="2 + 2 = ? ">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="human" placeholder="2 + 2 = ? " id="human">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="47" colspan="2">
                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var counter = 0;
```

function addNew(e) {

```
var countAll = document.getElementsByTagName("select").length - 1;

var lastSelectBox = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[countAll];

var items = lastSelectBox.innerHTML;

// Get the main Div in which all the other divs will be added
var mainContainer = document.getElementById('mainContainer');

// Create a new div for holding text and button input elements
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

// Create a new text input

var newText = document.createElement('select');
newText.type = "select"; 

newText.innerHTML = items;

//for testing

// Create buttons for creating and removing inputs
var newAddButton = document.createElement('input');
newAddButton.type = "button";
newAddButton.value = " + ";

var newDelButton = document.createElement('input');
newDelButton.type = "button";
newDelButton.value = " - ";

// Append new text input to the newDiv
newDiv.appendChild(newText);

// Append new button inputs to the newDiv
newDiv.appendChild(newAddButton);
newDiv.appendChild(newDelButton);

// Append newDiv input to the mainContainer div
mainContainer.appendChild(newDiv);

// Add a handler to button for deleting the newDiv from the mainContainer
newAddButton.onclick = addNew;

newDelButton.onclick = function() {
        mainContainer.removeChild(newDiv);
};
};
```

PHP

```
  <?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$Occasion = $_POST['Occasion'];
$Venues = $_POST['Venues'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$guests = $_POST['guests'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$from = $email; 
$to = 'ash.manterfield@btinternet.com'; 
$subject = 'New Menu Order';
$human = $_POST['human'];

$body = "From: $name\n Contact Number: $number\n E-Mail: $email\n Occasion: $Occasion\n  
Venues Looked At: $Venues\n Event Date: $date\n Number of Guests: $guests\n Custom    
Menu:\n $custom";

 if ($_POST['submit']) {
 if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
    if ($human == '4') {                 
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<h4>Your message has been sent!</h4>';
    } else { 
        echo '<h4>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</h4>'; 
    } 
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
    echo '<h4>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</h4>';
}
 } else {
    echo '<h4>You need to fill in all required fields!!</h4>';
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, a Q&A site for programming questions. Your question seems to be asking someone to do your work for you. That is offtopic on StackOverflow, and you should consider hiring someone to do the job. If that is not the case, add to your question what specific problem you are encountering and what you have tried to fix it, and trim your code so that we can re-create this problem, without having to spit through tons of other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove `<form>` tag there are twice in your html document.

As i answered your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316895/drop-down-lists-script/20318015#20318015).

Now if you want get all the select options values you should add to all the dropdown `text[]` name attribute. So PHP will know that these key is array.

You can still see the updated fiddle and inspecting it you'll see all select box name is same because they are treating as array by inserting `[]` in front of the name attribute see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mUwKj/10/).

For php you should do something like this:

PHP:

```
    <?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $Occasion = $_POST['Occasion'];
    $Venues = $_POST['Venues'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $guests = $_POST['guests'];
    $custom = $_POST['custom'];
    $from = $email; 
    $to = 'ash.manterfield@btinternet.com'; 
    $subject = 'New Menu Order';
    $human = $_POST['human'];
    $body = '';

    $body = "From: $name\n Contact Number: $number\n E-Mail: $email\n Occasion: $Occasion\n  
    Venues Looked At: $Venues\n Event Date: $date\n Number of Guests: $guests\n Custom    
    Menu:\n $custom";

if (is_array($_POST['text'])) {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($_POST['text'] as $key => $text) {
            $body .= "Option " . $key . ": " . $text . "\n";
            $count++;
        }
    }

     if ($_POST['submit']) {
     if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
        if ($human == '4') {                 
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<h4>Your message has been sent!</h4>';
        } else { 
            echo '<h4>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</h4>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<h4>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</h4>';
    }
     } else {
        echo '<h4>You need to fill in all required fields!!</h4>';
     }
     }
    ?>
```

Add above code after

```
$body = "From: $name\n Contact Number: $number\n E-Mail: $email\n Occasion: $Occasion\n  
Venues Looked At: $Venues\n Event Date: $date\n Number of Guests: $guests\n Custom    
Menu:\n $custom";
```

You'll get the list of values of all selectboxes named with `text[]`

Comment: cheers for that, I've updated the JS and PHP of which it gives me this error"array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "t3" [1]=> string(2) "t2" }"

Comment: Its not an error its array of values you got from select list. you have to loop through the array.

Comment: Im sorry to keep asking, ,but how do i do this?

Comment: thanks for that, but it still doesn't work, it adds the selected options but not the rest of the form data

Comment: What? you need to get the form data as you were doing earlier this method is just for the dropdown lists.

Comment: yes so the email i receive with the updated code above has just the selection boxes and not the rest of the text

Comment: @user2999825 copy full php code from above. See Edit!

Comment: You should implement this yourself.

Comment: just wondering if you can attach a CSS style to the buttons that are created through the javascript

Comment: it may work off the id

Comment: @user2999825 ok you are going off topic now please if you don't know the basic don't post questions until you know something basic. This is not the best place to get answer, related to each problem you're facing . It seems you are very beginner, you should consider to go for tutorials like HTML/CSS/Javascript/PHP

Answer (score 0):

For each select box you add, give it a name:

```
var select = document.createElement("select");
select.name = "abc";
```

You will be able to reference this in PHP like this:

```
$val = $_POST["abc"];
```

For each option you append, give it a value:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = "test";
option.innerHTML = "Opt 1";

select.appendChild(option);
```

When you choose "Opt 1," abc will be sent with the value "test."

Comment: thanks for that would you mind adding it to live code or all in to one javascript? I am very basic when it comes to javascript. Thank you for your help

Comment: @user2999825 what part do you need written?

Comment: the PHP and the Javascript

Comment: @user2999825 I'd rather you'd tell me exactly what you'd want so I can rewrite everything. It would be harder for me to read your code and try to figure out what you're doing.

Comment: Okay so I have a PHP form that uses text areas and drop down lists. The text areas are populated with data and the drop down lists. new drop down lists are added when on a click and options chosen, once all the options are chosen, the user clicks submit and the PHp sends the data including the data from the new drop down lists.

Comment: you can see it being used here (http://test.hdwebdesigns.co.uk/SIM/menu.php), the new dropdown lists and the options have to be sent with the PHP

Comment: @user2999825 OK, it might take some time, so be patient. :) Just remember that StackOverflow is mostly for code questions, *not* code files.

Comment: @user2999825 could you be specific on your menu options? Are you wanting sub selection? Let's say the user picks "salad," do you want a sub selection of "veggie salad," "fruit salad," etc?

Comment: hi no the list options are all the same for each box

Comment: @user2999825 so you just want a bunch of options and a plus button to add another bunch of options that are equal to the first box's?